# Left align single equation in gather

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations

How do I left align a single equation in `gather` environment?

```
\begin{gather}
a=1 \\ % How to left align this?
b=2 \\
\end{gather}
```

Comment: Are you open to using something other than `gather`? And what specifically do you mean by "left align"? Do you want `a=1` to be flush left with the text left margin?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant by left alignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on what you mean by left alignment of a single equation. Here are some options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,mathtools}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus augue velit, euismod in 
mauris sed, mattis vulputate urna. Curabitur mollis nunc arcu, eu pretium neque varius ac.
\begin{gather}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \\ % How to left align this?
  g(x) = x^2
\end{gather}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus augue velit, euismod in 
mauris sed, mattis vulputate urna. Curabitur mollis nunc arcu, eu pretium neque varius ac.
\begin{gather}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \\ % How to left align this?
  \mathrlap{g(x) = x^2}%
  \phantom{f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c}
\end{gather}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus augue velit, euismod in 
mauris sed, mattis vulputate urna. Curabitur mollis nunc arcu, eu pretium neque varius ac.
\begin{gather}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \\ % How to left align this?
  \mathmakebox[0pt]{\mathmakebox[\textwidth][l]{g(x) = x^2}}%
\end{gather}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus augue velit, euismod in 
mauris sed, mattis vulputate urna. Curabitur mollis nunc arcu, eu pretium neque varius ac.
\begin{align}
  &f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \\ % How to left align this?
  &g(x) = x^2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```